# Flutter method to fetch purchases history for iOS

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am currently handling user subscription logic in my android app coded in flutter using package `in_app_purchase: ^3.0.8`.

```
final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition = InAppPurchase.instance .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>(); 
final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse oldpurchases = await androidAddition.queryPastPurchases();
```

The above code fetches me all of the users purchases including non-consumables. But I don't find a similar method for `iOS`. How can I do the same for `iOS`? I found this link but still my problem is unresolved - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109523

Answer (score 0):

Fetching past purchases iOS.

am currently handling user subscription logic in my android app coded in flutter using package in_app_purchase: ^3.0.8.

final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition = InAppPurchase.instance .getPlatformAddition();
final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse oldpurchases = await androidAddition.queryPastPurchases();
The above code fetches me all of the users purchases including non-consumables. But I don't find a similar method for iOS. How can I do the same for iOS? I found this link but still my problem is unresolved - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109523

For iOS, you can use the appStore property provided by the InAppPurchase plugin to get the platform-specific addition for iOS. Then you can use the SKPaymentQueue class from the StoreKit framework to fetch the user's past purchases. Here's an example:

**

```
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';
final InAppPurchasePlugin purchasePlugin = InAppPurchasePlugin();
final AppStoreConnection appStoreConnection = AppStoreConnection.instance;
await purchasePlugin.connect();
final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await appStoreConnection.queryPastPurchases();
final List<PurchaseDetails> purchases = response.pastPurchases;
```

**
Make sure you have added the StoreKit framework to your iOS project and also set up the necessary certificates, entitlements and agreements in the Apple Developer portal for in-app purchases to work correctly.

Also, note that queryPastPurchases method from the InAppPurchase plugin is an asynchronous method and you need to wait for its response before accessing the purchases.

I hope this helps you to fetch the past purchases for iOS using the in_app_purchase package in Flutter.

Comment: Thanks much imad. Can you please elaborate from where I can import InAppPurchasePlugin and AppStoreConnection classes? Would be great if the code could be reproducible. I cannot find them in 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';

Comment: You don't  need to import it

Comment: Can you please point me to the documentation pages for InAppPurchasePlugin() and AppStoreConnection?